# HQL QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

Searched and found a lot of questions about this but nothing for my particular case. I am getting an error on my HQL query, here is the code:

```
final Query query = session.createQuery(
                    " SELECT DISTINCT e " +
                            " FROM Employee e" +
                            " INNER JOIN Requisition r on r.supervisor = e.id " +
                            " WHERE r.status = 'Open' " +
                            " AND r.isEvergreen = false " +
                            " AND r.isConfidential = false " +
                            " AND r.employmentType != 'Intern (Fixed Term)' " +
                            " AND (" +
                            "   CASE WHEN :searchString IS NOT NULL THEN (CONCAT(e.firstName, ' ', e.lastName) LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(:searchString), '%')) END)" +
                            " ORDER BY e.firstName, e.lastName")
                    .setParameter("searchString", searchString);
```

And here's the error log:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: CASE near line 1, column 329 [ SELECT DISTINCT e  FROM <Insert the rest of the query>
```

The query works if I remove the CASE WHEN statement in the final AND and the setParameter. So that means something is wrong with the final AND (...) and/or the newly introduced parameter.

I am new to Hibernate and am struggling with this since the error message isn't super helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case you have does not complete the condition.
You can simplify the case as follows :

```
(coalesce(:searchString,1,0) =1 OR e.firstName||' '|| e.lastName LIKE '%'||:searchString||'%')
```

- The first coalesce will check if searchstring is null , if it is will return 1 and 0 if it is not.
- If it returns 1 , the expression after OR will not get evaluated.
- If first expression return 0 , the expression after OR will be evaluated

This will fulfill your usecase to apply searchString filter only when it is not null.